# Docker Volumes - bind mount different filesystem to ../docker/volumes/

Tags: docker

Running docker v1.10.1 on RHEL 7.1 using btrfs driver. I have a separate xfs partition where I'd like to mount data volumes. I'd prefer to let docker manage the volumes natively (ie using docker volume create). Does anyone know if mounting the xfs partition at ./docker/volumes will work? Or is there a way to configure docker to use a different mount point (on a different filesystem) for data volumes?

Setup:

- Rhel 7.1
- Docker v1.10 Docker directory: /data-dev/docker  using btrfs
- Desired Mountpoint for data volumes: /data/docker/volumes using xfs

Question:

- Safe to mount /data/docker/volumes at /data-dev/docker/volumes?
- Alternatively, can I configure Docker to mount data volumes at /data/docker/volumes?

Answer (score 1):

For `docker version 17.09.0-ce`, you can create a named volume and after that, mount your partition in volume folder:

```
docker volume create yourNamedVolume
mount -t xfs /dev/sdXX /var/lib/docker/volumes/yourNamedVolume/_data
```

After that, all docker containers that you start with `--volume yourNamedVolume:/destination_folder` **will have your xfs data** in specified `destination_folder`.